# Changing BorderWidth in a table cell using google script

Tags: google-chrome

I  am trying to set  the top and bottom borders of a particular table cell. Setting the BORDER_WIDTH for the entire table is OK.

```
function myFunction() {
var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body=doc.getBody();
var tables=body.getTables();
tables[0].setBorderWidth(2);
```

It is also ok to use a style method

```
 var borderstyle={};
  borderstyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH]=2;

  tables[0].setAttributes(borderstyle);
```

I cannot see how to do the same to an individual cell

```
tables[0].getCell(2,2).setAttributes(borderstyle);
```

This method fails - documentation says BORDER_WIDTH only for TABLSE?
Any ideas??